# Search a device on paired devices Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am making an application to control a car using Bluetooth communication.

Something like [`this`](http://robotosh.blogspot.no/2012/07/controlling-lamp-using-pc-or-android.html), but with other options, because I want to control a car.

When I start the application with Bluetooth adapter disabled, ask me two times to enable Bluetooth.

I only have this to enable Bluetooth

```
public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
            Log.d(TAG, "Start - enable bluetooth");
        if(adaptadorBT==null){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth não é suportado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        } 
        else
        {
        Intent ativarBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(ativarBtIntent,REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        }   
    }
```

On LogCat i have

```
10-26 18:34:22.861: D/Bluetoothcar(29095): Start - enable bluetooth
10-26 18:34:22.971: D/Bluetoothcar(29095): ON DESTROY
10-26 18:34:23.031: D/Bluetoothcar(29095): Start - enable bluetooth
```

Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.bluetoothcar"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="14" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.bluetoothcar.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Comment: Do you get any exceptions when the app closes? If so, just go `try{ yourStuffGoesHere }except{ tryAginan }`.

Comment: You get that in LogCat? Have you tried debugging this code and seeing which part of the code is the problem? E.g. by using `Log.d("Bluetooth app","Got to this app stage")`.

Comment: Thanks Aleksander, The mobile phone I was using can't connect with adt because driver problems. I used another mobile phone, and insert some Log.d, found the problem and solved it. But the Bluetooth problem remains

Comment: Debugging always helps :) I don't have a phone at hand right now so couldn't do it myself, but glad it works.

Comment: But the bluetooth problem remains i don't know why my application execute "public void onStart" 2 times

Comment: OK well that's a whole different problem. Are you sure it's that method that's executed twice or could it be a very similar one or one that you call `onStart`? Post your manifest maybe, because it's `DalvikVM` that calls `onStart` and similar methods.